# What is the most common word for indicating a source of the citation? (e.g. Source:/Reference:/From:)

Tags: citation

For example,

> The Sun is the star at the center of the Solar System.
>
> **From**: Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun

What is the <del>best</del>most common word for the above bold part? 
From, Reference, Source, or else?

Not depending on the certain genre or style guide.

The context is a PowerPoint slide like this:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site! It depends on contect. In a note, you normally wouldn't use any word, just start with the name of whatever you are referring to. But not always. And at the end of an article, it may be different. So perhaps it would help if you added more context: what kind of document are we talking about? what's the genre? Are there any special conventions in this genre? P.S. [The Sun](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sun_%28United_Kingdom%29) may be big, but it's not a very respectable source!

Comment: Thanks. :) I added `what kind of document` to this question.  The genre is not limited to certain one.

Comment: Excellent! I would say all of these options are OK in a Powerpoint slide: *From(:) Wikipedia, Source: Wikipedia, Reference: Wikipedia,* or <nothing>. You could also do "Wikipedia on *Sun*" instead and leave out the link. Or do just the link and nothing else.

Comment: Cerberus
Thank you! Let me copy your comment to an answer.

Comment: When asking for "best word", always define what *best* is supposed to mean. Most common? Most unusual? The shortest? One that contains as many different letters as possible? The one recommended by some style guide? Which style guide?

Comment: @RegDwigнt Thank you for your suggestion. I fixed the question.

Answer (score 1):

Cerberus wrote:

> I would say all of these options are OK in a Powerpoint slide: From(:) Wikipedia, Source: Wikipedia, Reference: Wikipedia, or [nothing]. You could also do "Wikipedia on Sun" instead and leave out the link. Or do just the link and nothing else.